# How could I view absent and present with unique color code in winform C# gridview

Tags: c#

I have a table(PayRoll_AttendanceStatus) that contains 4 columns like

```
======================================
StatusID | Status | ShortName | color
======================================
   01    | Present|     P     |  Yellow
   02    | Absent |     A     |  Red
=======================================
```

from above mentioned table I used to mark day wise attendance into another table (PayRollMarkAttendance)and it contains values like

```
====================================================
MarkId  |  Employee_Code  |  StatusID  |  DateTime
====================================================
1       |        001      |    01      |  2016-06-11
2       |        002      |    02      |  2016-06-11
====================================================
```

For view I am using Pivot table and the code for pivot table is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT [EMPLOYEENAME] ,[EMPLOYEE_CODE]  ,[ShortName], 
DATENAME(M, [DateTime])as [Month]  ,DAY([DateTime]) as [DayValue] FROM
[View_PayRollMarkAttendance]) as Composite PIVOT (MAX([ShortName]) FOR
[DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10], [11], [12],
[13], [14],[15], [16], [17], [18], [19],[20], [21], [22], [23], [24],[25],
[26], [27], [28], [29],[30],[31])) AS PivotTable
```

Through this pivottable I can view my status quite good. But I want to view ABSENT AND PRESENT through its unique code color. Absent for Red and Present for Yellow.

Comment: If "winform gridview" == `DataGridView` I suggest you read up on the CellFormatting event

Comment: Sir, I tried CellFormatting event. But it is taking too much time to view. And I used to shorting the color automatically disappears,